# Replacing entries inside json file using shell script having same keys

Tags: json, bash, shell

I am having below part of a json file

```
   "field1": {
      "podSize": "S",
      "totalAuxVMs": 0
   },
   "field2": {
      "keyId": "sdfsafdgaadgfdasdfsdfdsfafgfdgfhfghgf"
   },
   "field3": {
      "keyId": "kdsahfkjdsfjsdfdsapodsporpow"
   },
   "field4": {

   }
```

I want to replace keyId of field2 and field3 separately. I tried sed but its not working. I tried below sed

```
sed -i 's/\"field2\": \{ \"keyId\":.*/\"field2\": \{ \"keyId\": '${new_key}'/g' "/path/to/my.json"
```

but it is giving error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 58: Unmatched \{
```

Any help, please.

Comment: Why aren't you using a proper JSON parser like jq top parse JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions for something it's not designed for is way too error prone. Please use a JSON parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) instead.

You can use its object editing extension...

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e '($json).field2.keyId:="'$new_key'"' | \
  xidel -s -          -e '($json).field3.keyId:="'$new_key'"'
```

...or (preferably) do it the XQuery 3.1 way...

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e 'map:merge(($json,({"field2":{"keyId":"'$new_key'"}},{"field3":{"keyId":"'$new_key'"}})),{"duplicates":"use-last"})'
```

Prettified query:

```
-e '
  map:merge(
    (
      $json,
      (
        {"field2":{"keyId":"'$new_key'"}},
        {"field3":{"keyId":"'$new_key'"}}
      )
    ),
    {"duplicates":"use-last"}
  )
'
```

Output:

```
{
  "field1": {
    "podSize": "S",
    "totalAuxVMs": 0
  },
  "field2": {
    "keyId": "<value of $new_key>"
  },
  "field3": {
    "keyId": "<value of $new_key>"
  },
  "field4": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jq to work on json:
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Anyway, if it is a restriction use the sed command, GNU sed has an option, -z, for null-separated records (lines).
The problem with your example is escaping special characters and line breaks.

Then, using the -z option, to change keyId value of field2:

```
sed -z 's/"field2": {\n  "keyId": "[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/"field2": {\n  "keyId": "newValue"/g' my.json
```

or for field3

```
sed -z 's/"field3": {\n  "keyId": "[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/"field3": {\n  "keyId": "newValue"/g' my.json
```

my.json contains your file.

Note that an exact match of the number of spaces is made, the pattern can be improved.